# Autocomplete Multiple Overflow on Y-Axis - Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I'm using Material UI Autocomplete Component with ' multiple ' attribute. Autocomplete is set to fixed width '250px'

Whenever I select more than 2 or 3 options, the Y-axis overflow which doesn't looks good.  [Image: Material UI Autocomplete overflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oajUD.png)

I'm using **limitTags**={1} but it only works when the Autocomplete is not selected.  How can I apply limitTags when the Autocomplete is selected?

Comment: can you create codesandbox example like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-forked-rh0e4p)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.